# Second view call in ViewDidAppear of first view with check of if plist exists

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

I am working on app, in which the first screen's ViewDidAppear has a check that if my plist at

```
NSString *path = [@"~Documents" stringByExpandingTildeInPath];
NSString *filePath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/data.plist",path];
```

exists then go to second view otherwise stay on first view at loadtime. The issue is that when i run my app in the simulator this check of if plist exists work but it doesn't work when i install my app on iphone device and then run it over there. I am stuck in this issue. Solutions are appreciated in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get the path to Documents directory in your application sandbox incorrectly, correct way will be:

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
```

Also, how do you put it to that folder? If that plist file is resource in your application then it is situated in application bundle initially and you need to copy it to documents folder before using it (if you want write access to it) or just read it from resources.

```
// Path to plist in application resources
NSString *resourcePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"data" ofType:@"plist];
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that your plist is copied into your project directory. If you added it without copying it then it will work in xcode and in the simulator but not when you copy your project to another computer and not when you load it onto the device.